Coroutines and parallelism
A small detail I'm confused about for coroutines.  I was told that the following code could run faster if I used coroutines:
fun processFiles() {
  val file1 = processFile("file1")
  val file2 = processFile("file2")
}

So if this was rewritten as
suspend fun processFiles(scope: CoroutineScope) {
  scope.launch { processFile("file1") }
  scope.launch { processFile("file2") }
}

It would be more efficient as the first coroutine is not blocking the second.  I agree that coroutines don't block, but why is it more efficient?  Coroutines are concurrent but not parallel unless you are running on a multi cpu machine.  Concurrency works via time slicing on a cpu.  So in my second example you may be in the middle of processing file1 for 5ms when you switch to processing file2 for 2ms before switching back to processing file1.
Let's say that it takes 2 seconds to process file1 and 5 seconds to process file 2.  It takes 7 seconds to process both files, regardless of switching between processing via coroutines or staying synchronous without coroutines, so why is it more efficient?
If you are running on a multi cpu machine, you can run the coroutines in parallel so code block 2 would take maxOf(timeForCoroutine1ToComplete, timeForCoroutine2ToComplete)=5.  But most computers run using a single cpu so arent blocks 1 and 2 equally efficient (synchronous without coroutines vs async with coroutines)?

Single CPU core machines are fairly rare these days, so perhaps whoever suggested a coroutine was making the assumption that that is also the case with your hardware? Whilst most machines have a single CPU, multiple cores on one CPU are more or less indistinguishable from multiple cores across multiple CPUs. AMD and Intel work very hard to make that so.

are you saying you can run coroutines in parallel on a single cpu if it's multi-core?

Yes and this is not specific to coroutines. Whenever you read anywhere about multiple CPUs, that usually means either multiple processors or multiple cores. From the application perspective it is pretty much the same.

Coroutines are for concurrence and nor parallelism indeed. However, IO-operations can be faster with concurrence. Parallelism is not always needed to make them faster. In fact, it can sometimes be detrimental (e.g. on most HDDs). For example, with network operation you can send data to 1 client in a first coroutine and then switch to the second to do the same for another client, before switching back to the first and wait a response. This is better than waiting directly for the response of the first client.

The same thing applies for storage devices, though in practice the stack is not always designed to be really concurrent. Libc reads are blocking whether coroutines are used or not. Some system APIs (eg. io_uring)  enable you to really do async operations in coroutines so you can avoid usual waits. Asynchronous operations can be either done using kernel threads or directly supported by the device stack (truly async operation supported by the driver+firmware). Coroutines alone are not enough to make things faster in this case (except maybe for write which are partially async yet).

Re, "Coroutines are concurrent but not parallel..." Bear in mind that when people say "parallel" in this context, they usually are talking about parallel processing. That is to say, they are talking about the ability of a program to perform more calculations in a given amount of time than what any single CPU can perform in the same span of time. But if your program spends a significant amount of real time waiting for I/O devices or network packets, then ditto what Jérôme Richard
said in comments above. Concurrently waiting for things is a sorta-kinda weak "parallelism."
